# Singleton Property causing App crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, singleton

I have a singelton class which is used to pull and store all data from a Web Service. The class has an NSArray and an NSDictionary which stores the data. I then want to use this data to populate tableviews in other views.

In one of my views, within the View Did Load method, I tell the singleton to retrieve the data from the web service and store it (it successfully retrieves the data, I logged it). I then try to access the data like so:

[[ClubData initClubData] memberData];

If I try to use that to populate the table view, it crashes and keeps referencing some kind of view. One time it referenced CALayer, another time a WrapperView ??? Am I not doing something right

My Singleton:

```
#import "ClubData.h"
#import "JSON.h";

@implementation ClubData
@synthesize conn, response, url, api_calls, memberData, beerData, call;

static ClubData *globalClubData = nil;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Instance Methods

- (void)getBeerData {

}

- (void)getSingleBeer:(NSInteger *)beerID {
}

- (void)getClubData {

    //check for existing data
    if (memberData != nil)
        return;

    //init
    memberData = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    //create request
    call = @"memberlist";
    [self initRequest:@"memberlist"];

}

- (void)getMemberData:(NSInteger *)memberID {
}

- (void)parseData:(NSString *)json {

    //parse based on call type

    if (call == @"memberlist") {
        memberData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        memberData = [json JSONValue];
    }

    //reset call
    [call release];
    call = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Connection & Delegate

- (void)initRequest:(NSString *)type {

    //build url
    NSMutableString *rURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:url];
    [rURL appendString:[api_calls objectForKey:type]];
    NSURL *tempURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:rURL];
    [rURL release];

    //init request & create connection
    NSURLRequest *request = [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:tempURL] autorelease];
    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [tempURL release];

    //init response
    response = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

//receive data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [response appendData:data];
}

//connection complete
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    //release conn
    [conn release];

    //parse JSON
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [response release];

    //parse
    [self parseData:json];
    [json release];

}

//connection failed
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                                                    message:@"Unable to connect to network. Network required to load data."
                                                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];    
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Control

+ (ClubData *)initClubData {
    if (globalClubData == nil) {
        @synchronized(self) {
            globalClubData = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    }
    return globalClubData;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        //set url
        url = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"https://myurl.com/path/to/script.php?action=get_app_data"] retain];

        //possible calls
        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"beerlist", @"singlebeer", @"memberlist", nil];
        NSArray *objs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"&subaction=beerlist", @"&subaction=singlebeer&beerID=", @"&subaction=memberlist", nil];
        api_calls = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objs forKeys:keys] retain];

        [keys release];
        [objs release];

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifecycle

- (void)dealloc {
    [conn release];
    [response release];
    [url release];
    [call release];
    [api_calls release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm curious about the static GlobalClubData being outside the init function. The examples I have seen declare it inside the sharedInstance method.

Comment: In the apple documentation, it was outside. Hence why I put it there. I have no idea honestly. Web Developer by trade trying to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
api_calls = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objs forKeys:keys] retain];
```

do not retain it (you are already an owner of that object).

As for the crash - post the stack trace.

Edit: Probably found:

```
if (call == @"memberlist") {
    memberData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init]; //remove this (it is redundant and causes leak)
    memberData = [json JSONValue]; //retain this
}
```

Comment: Thanks, retaining the object worked perfectly! I do have one more question however. I am calling that method (to retrieve the data) in the viewWillLoad method of my TableClass (In order to keep it from loading if that view is never...viewed). How can I check to see if that data is loaded. Cause when I call the [[self tableView] reloadData], it doesn't necessarily work due to the fact that the data hasn't loaded. Does that make sense? Perhaps I should post as a new question.

Comment: do that in viewDidLoad not in viewWillLoad

Comment: Ok. That is not a resource issue? I assumed not to do it there because what if the user never clicks that view? It would load that data for no reason. Or is it just not that big of a deal?

Comment: Is TableClass a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: The class which utilizes this singleton, and has the table view object, is a subclass of UITableViewController

Comment: then place the loading code into viewWillAppear. It is only called when view is shown

Comment: Yea that is what I was doing. But how can I tell when the data has finished loading from within my TableViewController class?